# Format string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this string:

```
var comments = "2020-01-15 15:06:53 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais)\nTESTE: Comentários adicionais.\n\n2020-01-15 14:47:39 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais)\nChecado problema no servidor.\n\n";

console.log(comments);
```

```
2020-01-15 15:06:53 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais)
TESTE: Comentários adicionais.

2020-01-15 14:47:39 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais)
Checado problema no servidor.
```

I would like to format to an array, like this:
The length of this array can increase or decrease.

```
['2020-01-15 15:06:53 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais) TESTE: Comentários adicionais.', '2020-01-15 14:47:39 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais) Checado problema no servidor.']
```

I tried with this command, but I didn't have the desired result.

```
console.log(comments.split('\n'));
```

```
[
  '2020-01-15 15:06:53 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais)\n' +
    'TESTE: Comentários adicionais.',
  '2020-01-15 14:47:39 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais)\n' +
    'Checado problema no servidor.',
  ''
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like what you really want is to split at double line breaks, then remove the single line breaks from inside each entry.

```
comments.split('\n\n').map(comment => comment.replace(/\n/g, ' ')).filter(comment => comment);
```

Comment: Nit pick: The linebreaks should be replaced by a space, not removed completely.

Comment: You would still have an empty key in the array left. Use `filter` to remove that key from the array.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yep, I didn't see the ending `\n\n` in the input. Just added a quick little shorthand for removing empty strings from the array :)

Comment: Mapping is crazy.

Comment: @AlexandreLage Mapping is *useful* FTFY :D

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, you gotta study performance. This .filter(), .map(), after .split() is going to break your application if your string has little more than few items.

Answer (score 1):

Make a non greedy match of a sequence of space and non space characters `[\S\s]+?`, that has a sequence of two \n after it `(?=\n{2})`. Afterwards replace the remaining `\n` to spaces.

```js
var comments = "2020-01-15 15:06:53 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais)\nTESTE: Comentários adicionais.\n\n2020-01-15 14:47:39 - Rafael Souza (Comentários adicionais)\nChecado problema no servidor.\n\n";

var result = comments.match(/[\S\s]+?(?=\n{2})/g)
  .map(str => str.replace(/\n/g, ' '))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mind performance:

`.split()` accepts regex:

Use `comments.split(/[\n]{2}[^$]/)`

Which is equivalent to `comments.split(/\n\n[^$]/)`

It will split the string using `\n\n\` as a patter except when `$` (end of line) follows it.

Just a piece of information:

> If separator appears at the beginning or end of the string, or both, the array begins, ends, or both begins and ends, respectively, with an empty string.

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split